# Cannot uninstall app via adb

Tags: adb, installation, uninstallation, mediatek, smartwatch

I'm trying to update an app on a smartwatch, but whatever I try, I ran into errors.

1. `adb install newversion.apk` => `[INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]`
2. `adb install -r -d newversion.apk` => `[INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]`
3. `adb uninstall {packagename}` => Failure `[DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]`

4a) `adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 {packagename}` => success

4b) `adb install newversion.apk` => `[INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]`

App is a launcher. OS has no launcher now. I still cannot install my new version.

Checking for other users: `pm list users` -> `users: UserInfo{0:Owner:13} running`.

So I'm the only user. Also tried the `uninstall --user` command with other user IDs like 0, 1, 10-15, 2000+, 300+, all nothing.

I am not rooted. `su` does not work. It's an MT6739 chipset with Android 7.1.1 running.

Nothing that I try lets me install my new app. Also not after factory reset.

Comment: I would assume that you are trying to install an app that sues a package name already used by a system app on that device but your app has a different signature and thus can't be installed as update. I would recommend to repackage the app e.g. apktool decompile, modify app name, recompile, resign) and then install it using a different package name to avoid those problems.

Comment: Not possible. The old app on the system is the problem. new app should not be changed.

Comment: Then you have to identify the APK on system partition and delete it.

Comment: But that requires root rights I believe? I dont have root....

Comment: Sorry I misread what you wrote about root. Usually people don't mention `su` if their device is not rooted. Then you only have the option to modify the APK that should be installed.

Comment: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE implies that <pkgname> is still "a known candidate" - do you mix up package name with file name? also some system apps are odex and can't un/installed by adb. are you sure it is **your** new app/version? did update version code in manifest properly?